# Can't vote for offtopic close

Tags: support, close-reasons, close-dialog

I used to be able to flag questions for being off-topic  belonging to another Stack Exchange site. But now my dialog looks like this:

Was the feature removed, renamed or is it a bug?

As the top line mentions "Belong to another Stack Exchange" I think this option should be there.

> - Vote to close questions that could be improved, may already have answers, or belong on another Stack Exchange site.
> - Duplicate
>   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
> - A community-specific reason
>   This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.
> - Needs details or clarity
>   This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
> - Needs more focus
>   This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.
> - Opinion-based
>   This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: You need to navigate to "A community-specific reason" (which is what Off-Topic was renamed to - voting for migration hasn't moved from that spot)

Comment: Note that the option disappears if the question is too old. (it was previously there if the question was too old to be migrated, but it said it was too old. Now it's just gone)